# Changing the Access Mask in Powershell (File Share Permissions)

Tags: powershell, permissions, share

I'm trying to make a Share Folder on a Remote Server with PowerShell, where **Everyone** needs to have a Full Control Permission. It is really easy to change that in Security, but for Share Permission there is not so much information on the web.
Although i can get the information about the Access Mask:

```
$folder='Profile'
$setting = get-wmiobject -Class Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting -ComputerName nano-03 -filter "Name='$folder'"


$setting.GetSecurityDescriptor().Descriptor.Dacl | Select @{Name="Domain";Expression={$_.Trustee.Domain}},@{Name="Name";Expression={$_.Trustee.Name}},AccessMask


#here is more specify
$setting.GetSecurityDescriptor().Descriptor.Dacl | Where {$_.trustee.name -eq 'Everyone'}
```

and the value is **1179817**, but i need it to be **2032127** for Full Control

There is a method SetSecurityDescriptor(), but i don't know how to use it properly. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Which PowerShell version?

Comment: I have 5.1.14393.693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using an up to date version of PowerShell, you can use `New-SmbShare` to create the share and set permissions:

```
New-SmbShare –Name MySharedFolder –Path C:\folder\MySharedFolder -FullAccess Everyone
```

This cannot be run directly against a remote computer, so you will need to use `Invoke-Command` to run it remotely:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock { New-SmbShare –Name MySharedFolder –Path C:\folder\MySharedFolder -FullAccess Everyone }
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command` assumes remoting is enabled.  If the target is a Server2012 install, that's a fine assumption.